# Simple Commander Waypoints Foxy

Tags: ros-foxy

I have a question:

### What I want to achieve

In rviz2 (foxy) is the waypoint mode in the nav2 panel but I want to interact programmatically with the waypoint mode.

### My Problem

I using foxy as distro. Unfortuneately, simple_commander don't exist for foxy.

### My Approach

Therefore, I copy paste the simple commander folder (from humble) inside of my nav2 package of my workspace (I build nav2 stack from source). Colcon build gave me some errors and warning. I fixed them all step by step. I added some actions and msg in the nav2_msg package. For example, if you open robot_navigator.py, you'll see in import AssistedTeleop in line 26 it's whited out. After I added the necessary files, it's not whited out anymore and the error/warning disappear.

Now colcon build works without an error or warnings. I can also set the initial pose and send a single goal programmatically. However, the simple commander waypoint mode don't work. Its always showing:

```
[INFO] [1694809146.773522212] [basic_navigator]: Nav2 is ready for use!
[INFO] [1694809147.776931425] [basic_navigator]: 'FollowWaypoints' action server not available, waiting...
[INFO] [1694809148.779486553] [basic_navigator]: 'FollowWaypoints' action server not available, waiting...
[INFO] [1694809149.782442363] [basic_navigator]: 'FollowWaypoints' action server not available, waiting...
[INFO] [1694809150.785148441] [basic_navigator]: 'FollowWaypoints' action server not available, waiting...
[INFO] [1694809151.787991259] [basic_navigator]: 'FollowWaypoints' action server not available, waiting...
```

Moreover, the action /FollowWaypoint is available (ROS2 action list):

```
robot@robot:~$ ros2 action list
/FollowWaypoints
/assisted_teleop
/backup
/compute_path_through_poses
/compute_path_to_pose
/follow_path
/follow_waypoints
/navigate_through_poses
/navigate_to_pose
/smooth_path
/spin
/wait
```

### My Question

I forgot something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which one of these is not like the others, which one of these just doesn’t belong

You can see the WPF action is CamelCase while the rest are snake_case. We fixed that ages ago in the modern Nav2 distributions, but the WPF in the simple navigator is expecting it to be the corrected version.

It should be a one-line change in the python class to adjust the action interface string to the “broken” CamelCase version.

Comment: Thank you Steve !
I really appreciate your help ;)